# Uso de AddressOf en C# sin delegados

Tags: c#, vb

Tengo una dll externa que tengo que utilizar en C#. Esta dll externa tiene un método al que se le pasa un puntero a un método de mi código.
En el código antiguo se utilizaba la función AddressOf de VB pero ahora lo tengo que hacer con C#. Todo lo que he leído es utilizando delegados, pero, ¿se puede hacer de alguna otra forma?

La declaración del método original en VB es el siguiente:

```
Private Declare Sub ReceiveMessage Lib "xxx.dll" (ByVal lngProcAddress As Long)
```

Y el uso de este método:

```
ReceiveMessage AddressOf GetMessages
```

¿Como puedo usar el método de esta dll en C#?

Edito para añadir la declaración del metodo en C#:

```
[DllImport("xxx.dll", EntryPoint = "ReceiveMessage", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void ReceiveMessage(long lngProcAddress);
```

El metodo GetMessages es el siguiente:

```
public void GetMaMessages(int command)
{
    switch (command) {
        case 100: Show(); break;
        case 501: Exit(); break;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Edito para dar la solución que he encontrado:

Se necesita un delegado:

```
public delegate void MyMessages(int command, long from);
```

El uso:

```
ReceiveMessage(Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new MyMaMessages(GetMaMessages)).ToInt64());
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Agrega tambien como llamas a ReceiveMessage (la porcion del codigo que usas)

Answer (score 1):

Despues de hacer algunas busquedas, porque me quede con la duda, parece ser que no necesitas ningun delegado para hacer esto.

C# pasa implicitamente la direccion del procedimiento y crea el delegado.

Por lo cual lo siguiente deberia funcionar:

```
ReceiveMessage (GetMessages)
```

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi, pero como he puesto en el caso, lo de utilizar delegados no funciona. Es lo primero que he intentado utilizar pero C# da un error:

CS1503  C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'long'

Comment: Puedes aclarar en la pregunta la cabecera de la funcion GetMessages??? si no es void, puede que el error sea ahi...

Comment: Y otra cosa mas.. aclara como viene el codigo. Estas seguro que el problema es el pase de la funcion, y no otra cosa?

Comment: La dll es externa y no se que tiene en su interior. En el codigo de VB se le pasaba un puntero al metodo y esa dll llamaba al método para devolver un numero para mostrar o cerrar el programa.

Comment: Pero el metodo GetMessages necesita recibir un parametro.. como le pasarias el parametro?

Comment: No se como se hacia en VB, pero teniendo el puntero, parece que podía llamar al método y pasarle los parámetros.

Comment: La funcion en VB recibia un parametro? o tenia una variable global que usaba como parametro? Si la funcion de la DLL solo recibe un puntero a una funcion, no puede recibir un parametro (en cualquier lenguaje). fijate de pasarle una funcion sin parametros, a ver si sigue tirandote el error.